# My Shell Script is not breaking using exit within nested logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a shell script which is running some scripts sequentially and also in paralell. That execution workflow is working as expected. However, when the last script G.py for region 4 completes, it does not break the entire script. I tried `exit` and `break` but none of them work. Here is the script:

```
python A.py       --region="$region1"
python B.py       --region="$region1"
python C.py       --region="$region1"
python D.py       --region="$region1"
{
  python A.py     --region="$region2"
  python B.py     --region="$region2"
  python C.py     --region="$region2"
  python D.py     --region="$region2"
  {
  python A.py     --region="$region3"
  python B.py     --region="$region3"
  python C.py     --region="$region3"
  python D.py     --region="$region3"
     {

  python A.py     --region="$region4"
  python B.py     --region="$region4"
  python C.py     --region="$region4"
  python D.py     --region="$region4"
  python E.py     --region="$region4"
  python F.py     --region="$region4"
  python G.py     --region="$region4"
  exit;
     } & python E.py --region="$region3"  ; python F.py --region="$region3" ; python G.py --region="$region3" &
  } & python E.py --region="$region2"  ; python F.py --region="$region2" ; python G.py --region="$region2" &
} & python E.py --region="$region1"  ; python F.py --region="$region1" ; python G.py --region="$region1" &
```

After G.py for region4 is done, it does not break the script. My task manager shows it is still running but with 0% CPU utilization. The terminal shows this output:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: We need a [mre] -- code *someone else can run themselves without changes* to see the problem. Something that requires an `A.py` nobody but you has is not a valid reproducer.

Comment: ...that said, it looks like the `exit` causes that single/specific shell run in the background with `&` to exit, but that doesn't stop the whole script. It's the bash equivalent to as if you used `os.fork()` to make a new process that's a copy of your existing Python interpreter -- calling `sys.exit()` in it only makes that one copy exit. Similarly, if you do `{ echo "this is in the child process"; exit; } & echo "this is in the original process"` in bash, only the child process is impacted by the `exit`.

Comment: thank you for the pointer. what command can I use to terminate the parent process once G.py for region 4 is done?

Comment: (to be clear, while only parens and not curly braces _force_ a subshell to be created, using `&` also creates a new subshell, which is how you end up with a separate process that your `exit` gets scoped to).

Comment: Well -- normally, I'd structure things differently and put the thing you want to exit on completion of in the parent, not in one of the children.

Comment: ...however, you can always use `kill` to send signals to other processes, and you can use `trap` to set up signal handlers in those processes to act on those signals when they're received (so f/e, you can have a signal handler in the parent that kills the _other_ children as well, when it's fired; presumably you'd use something like `wait` in the parent to block until either a signal is received or all the children exit on their own).

Comment: If you press enter after G is done, does it appear to finish?

Comment: @thatotherguy I want to exit the entire script once all jobs (last one being G.py for region 4) are done. how would i do this? And yes, when I press enter key it ends it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that your script fails to exit, but that it exits too soon.

Since the script exits relatively quickly, you get your prompt back early. However, the background jobs keep showing output, overwriting and obscuring this prompt.

When you later look at the terminal, you only see job output and no prompt, so you think the script is still running.

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ sleep 1; seq 1 3; } &
```

And here's the output:

```
$ ./myscript
$ 1
2
3
```

If you look carefully, you see the new prompt before the `1`, but the end of the output is `3` so it could look like the script is still running. However, if you just type blindly, you'll see that you're talking to your shell as normal.

To make the script behave as expected, make sure to wait for all your backgrounded jobs.

In the example script, this can be done with a simple `wait`, but in your case, you will need to add `wait` at the end of every block that starts something in the background:

```
python A.py       --region="$region1"
python B.py       --region="$region1"
python C.py       --region="$region1"
python D.py       --region="$region1"
{
  python A.py     --region="$region2"
  python B.py     --region="$region2"
  python C.py     --region="$region2"
  python D.py     --region="$region2"
  {
  python A.py     --region="$region3"
  python B.py     --region="$region3"
  python C.py     --region="$region3"
  python D.py     --region="$region3"
     {

  python A.py     --region="$region4"
  python B.py     --region="$region4"
  python C.py     --region="$region4"
  python D.py     --region="$region4"
  python E.py     --region="$region4"
  python F.py     --region="$region4"
  python G.py     --region="$region4"
     } & python E.py --region="$region3"  ; python F.py --region="$region3" ; python G.py --region="$region3" &
  wait
  } & python E.py --region="$region2"  ; python F.py --region="$region2" ; python G.py --region="$region2" &
  wait
} & python E.py --region="$region1"  ; python F.py --region="$region1" ; python G.py --region="$region1" &
wait
```

Note that you don't even need the `exit` anymore.